# jQuery.Dunatree.How to load JSON tree using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using [jQuery.dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html) plugin,  how to load JSON formatted data using AJAX? 
I do all as said in documentation:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#Tree" ).dynatree({
        title:"Thetree",
        imagePath:'/jquery/css/',
        selectMode:1,
        initAjax:{
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:2013/jsfolderstree"
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

The JS scripts is correctly connected to the HTML page, witout errors.
The requested URL by AJAX returns valid JSON:

```
[{
 "key": "0x55638DB3",
 "children": [
  {
   "key": "0x5D43E57C",
   "children": [
    {
     "key": "0x70A4C1CE",
     "children": [
      {
       "key": "0x799E9590",
       "children": [],
       "expand": true,
       "tooltip": "This is group 5",
       "isFolder": true,
       "title": "Group  5"
      },{
       "key": "0x78C952A8",
       "children": [],
       "expand": true,
       "tooltip": "This is group 6",
       "isFolder": true,
       "title": "Group 6"
      }],
     "expand": true,
     "tooltip": "This is group 3",
     "isFolder": true,
     "title": "Group 3"
    }],
   "expand": true,
   "tooltip": "This is group 1",
   "isFolder": true,
   "title": "Group  1"
  },{
   "key": "0x45B98999",
   "children": [
    {
     "key": "0x6C829354",
     "children": [],
     "expand": true,
     "tooltip": "This is group 4",
     "isFolder": true,
     "title": "Group  4"
    }],
   "expand": true,
   "tooltip": "This is group 2",
   "isFolder": true,
   "title": "Group  2"
  },{
   "key": "0x47BE4570",
   "children": [],
   "expand": true,
   "tooltip": "This is group 7",
   "isFolder": true,
   "title": "Group 7"
  }],
 "expand": true,
 "tooltip": "Main level of tree",
 "isFolder": true,
 "title": "Root"
}]
```

But in result I have message "Loading Error" amd nothing more...
Where is my mistake?

I need load some JSON tree to the web-page, the tree must have methods to get selected node, and visual selection by mouse, that is that I need. Maybe need to use more simple plugins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using jQuery ajax to load a JSON data,jQuery will resolve JSON data by JSON.parse method.
So don't put your JSON data in [], it will call parse error in jQuery ajax method.

```
{
 "key": "0x55638DB3",
 "children": [{...}]
 ....
}
```